# Moving "My Account" link from the top links in 2.2

Tags: magento2, layout, toplinks

having trouble with a layout change in Mage 2.2.

I want to move just the link for "My Account" from its current position (located inside `<div class="panel header"> <ul class="header links">`), to the `<div class="header content">` (which contains the logo and cart).

I tried using the code snippet `<move element="authorization-link-login" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />`
 but this doesn't seem to do anything at all. This is strange as I am using something similar to move my search to just before the logo (`<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="-"/>`).

Can anyone shine any light on why I can't get the link to move?

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue. I found a link from October at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11431 that seems to be similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<move element="my-account-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
```